# Group By to return multiple different grouped results SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregation

I don't think this is going to be too rough, though I am not seeing it in the asked questions and answered questions.

I am looking for a way to group by sales person for two different types of sales.

So something like

```
Name PendingORders CompletedOrders TotalOrders
```

Grouped by the Name first, Count Type = P, Count = C and then sum Type= P and count = C.

Though there are only two types of orders in this report so technically the criteria is just a count of all orders by the name.

My table, would look like this

```
Name|Order#|Type
Jane| 1    | C
Jane| 2    | P
Jane| 3    | P
Fred| 4    | P
Fred| 5    | P
```

Hopefully the query would produce

```
Name|TotalOrder|Pending|Completed 
Jane|3         |2      |1
Fred|2         |2      |0
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Just a comment on your table. You would never build a table that had the names in it like that. Anytime you see multiple values of the same type in a table, it means that there should be another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're basically just grouping by salesperson and computing three different aggregates for each.  That's completely straightforward:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  count(*) AS TotalOrder,
  SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pending,
  SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed,
FROM orders
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
select Name
       TotalOrder = count(Name),
       Completed = count(case when type = 'C' then 1 end),
       PENDING = count(case when type = 'P' then 1 end)
From yourtable
group by Name
```

or use `Pivot`

```
SELECT Name,
       TotalOrder,
       Completed = C,
       PENDING = P
FROM   (SELECT *,
               TotalOrder=Count(1)OVER(partition BY name)
        FROM   Yourtable) a
       PIVOT (Max(order#)
             FOR type IN ([C],
                          [P]))pv
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out your problem using temp tables.  You have to use conditional (CASE WHEN) statements to work out the math then group by name.

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders (
Name VARCHAR(25) NULL , 
OrderNumber INT NULL , 
OrderType CHAR(1) NULL )



INSERT INTO #Orders (Name, OrderNumber , OrderType)
    VALUES ( 'Jane' , 1 , 'C') , 
           ( 'Jane' , 2 , 'P') , 
           ( 'Jane' , 3 , 'P') , 
           ( 'Fred' , 4 , 'P') , 
           ( 'Fred' , 5 , 'P') 



 SELECT Name , 
        COUNT(*) AS TotalOrder , 
        SUM(CASE OrderType WHEN 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pending , 
        SUM(CASE OrderType WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed  
   FROM #Orders
  GROUP BY Name 

 DROP TABLE #Orders
```